# C# TCPClient Write-Only connection

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, tcpclient, socketexception

So I'm currently working on an C# application in VisualStudio, using an TCPClient and I get the following error when calling the `Connect` function:

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address 
(protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Here the whole function:

```
localAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0];
serverAddress = IPAddress.Parse(serverAddressString);

ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, clientPort);
ipServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddress, serverPort);

socket = new TcpClient(ipLocalEndPoint);
socket.Connect(ipServerEndPoint);
```

I know why this error occurs and my guess to fix this, is to create a connection which only sends packets to the server.

Is there a way to actually create this kind of connection?

Because of my lack of experience, I could be completely wrong and actually need to hook onto the application and use the applications connection.

Comment: So, you can't read data from the server?  Doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well I don't need to read data from the server. That's the point.

Comment: You are opening more than one connection so why will  sending message fix this issue?  there is a type broadcast message but it is UDP not TCP.  TCP allows for multiple connections to same server but the connection must be from a different source IP address.

Comment: Where does all this misinformation come from?  The message from the exception is itself incorrect, @jdweng got closer to a correct statement of the restriction but still missed (TCP connection is identified by 4 factors, so it is possible for local IP, remote IP, and remote port to all be the same as long as the local port is different, see for example browser settings like `network.http.max-connections-per-server`).  This question is unanswerable until we find out what function threw the `SocketException`.  The current description "using a `TCPClient`" is not adequate.

Comment: TCP doesn't know anything about clients or servers. The client/server concept is an application-layer concept. TCP creates connections between peers, and either peer can send over the connection, and in fact, that is a requirement of TCP for things like ACKs. Whether or not one off the peer applications is listening for data is a different matter.

Comment: Thanks for all the information!  
@BenVoigt The `SocketException` is thrown by the `Connect` function

Comment: @RonMaupin: TCP does have a concept of a bound & listening endpoint, and an initiating endpoint.  The two peers are not equal, at least for the purposes of connection establishment.  Usually (really, almost always) the first is called "server" and the second is called "client".

Comment: @Kjosu: Are you calling any functions between construction and connect?  For example, binding a specific client port, or enabling non-blocking mode?

Comment: @BenVoigt, if you look at the definition of TCP, which is _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_, you will find that there are no clients or servers. Each end of a TCP connection is an equal peer. The client/server concept is an application-layer concept. Binding and listening is an application function.

Comment: @RonMaupin: The endpoints are unequal at the protocol level.  One sends SYN, the other sends SYN+ACK.  I suppose you're looking at the RFC statement that "Two processes which issue active OPENs to each other at the same time will be correctly connected." but that RFC is quite out of date, and that claim isn't true in modern TCP (where sequence numbers are unpredictable and verified)

Comment: @BenVoigt, both sides can send to the other side, and either side can close the connection, and each side must ACK segments from the other side. It's all spelled out in the RFC. The RFC makes it clear that both sides are peers, regardless of the side that initiated the connection. In fact, there are application servers that initiate connections to application clients. At TCP, there is no client or server.

Comment: @Ron: The equality doesn't start until the connection is established.  But this question is about the establishment phase.

Comment: @BenVoigt, OK, OK, you know more about TCP than the IETF. The RFC has nothing about clients or servers for TCP. It does discuss service processes, which are in the application-layer, not transport-layer where TCP lives. I guess a server application that initiates a TCP connection to a client application, is not really a server, and the client application is not really a client.

Comment: @RonMaupin: You're attacking a strawman.  I have only said that the two endpoints are not equal during setup and teardown, there definitely is one listening and one initiating.  And the listening one is USUALLY called a server.  Coming up with limited counterexamples (like active-mode FTP data connection, which is initiated by the FTP server and accepted by the FTP client) does not disprove the distinguishability of the two endpoints.  It should not be a surprise that today's network engineers know more about modern TCP than the authors of RFC 793 did when they wrote historic TCP 37 years ago.

Comment: @Ron But if all of this was meant to prove there's no such thing as a one-way TCP connection, all you needed was the second half of your comment where you mention ACKs, or the 3-way handshake.  It doesn't actually matter whether the peers are indistinguishable, distinguishable only during establishment, or always distinguishable.  Bidirectional dataflow is a requirement for TCP.

Comment: I added the function where the exception occurs.

But I think my guess of a write-only connection was pretty thoughtless.